# sql select a column if

Tags: sql

Within SQL is it possible to select a column only if it meets my Criteria?

```
IF p.Amount != 0.0 
    { select p.Amount from Price p }
```

This is part of a much larger SQL will be used to filter the column from being displayed if there are values over 0.0

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want different rows of result set have different columns? That's not possible.

Comment: Please elaborate.  Your query is showing results when values are over 0.0, but the text says the opposite.  And, what are you going to do with the values?

Answer (score 4):

SQL criteria are used to select rows, not columns. I have generally found it makes life easier to always select the same columns for a specific query, and later choose whether or not to display them using view logic.

Comment: +1, decided to finally upvote your answer (though it looks more like a comment to me) as the only one that doesn't give a definite solution for indefinite problem ;-)

Comment: thanks, although it's possible to select different output columns using dynamic SQL, I would not recommend it unless it was the last available option. @Will seems to just want to only display a column under certain circumstances, probably much better (and easier) to do this in the UI.

Comment: the criterion used to select column seems to be dependent on the row. Whether this is what what the OP meant I don't know. On the other hand this `select p.amount from price p` part could be read as select all amounts from price. But then it's not clear what `p` refers to in condition... Again - what I like about your answer is that it does *not* provide a solution without finding out what the problem is ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `CASE` statement. [Transact-SQL - CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT   ProductNumber, Category =
      CASE ProductLine
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'
         WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'
         ELSE 'Not for sale'
      END,
   Name
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber;
GO
```

Comment: I'm not sure which versions of SQL this will work for, certainly none that I have seen

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to not be visible at all? Or just display some other predefined value inside it?
Because if you want the column to not appear at all, but only in some cases, that can not be done. 
However, you can return a different result in the column, should it suffice for you. Use CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN p.amount< 700 THEN p.amount
ELSE 0
END
FROM Price p;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show values greater than 0.0, you can use a `where` clause:

```
select p.amount
from t
where p.amount > 0
```

If you want non-positive values to be shown, and blanks (NULLs) for the rest, then do:

```
select (case when p.amount > 0 then p.amount end)
from t
```

If you only want rows returns when *all* values are greater then zero, then here is one way:

```
select p.amount
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when p.amount > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over () as Pgt0
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where Pgt0 = cnt
```

If you actually want to remove the column when, say, all the values are the same, then you need a more complicated expression.  SQL SELECT queries define the columns and don't have dynamically configurable columns.

Answer (score -1):

You can use IFF function in SQL Server:

```
SELECT IIF(p.Amount != 0.0 ) as amount

FROM price p
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have an iif function.